# Question about NSolve

Tags: equation-solving, polynomials

there!

For some purposes I need to be able to write a code in C# that could find all roots of the equations system, consisting of two-variable polynomial expressions, like the folliwing:

```
-350.499 - 5.66589 u + 50.5865 u^2 - 23.531 u^3 - 126.875 v + 
  210.131 u v - 473.396 u^2 v + 227.696 u^3 v + 40.9534 v^2 - 
  343.547 u v^2 + 747.81 u^2 v^2 - 313.21 u^3 v^2 - 33.374 v^3 + 
  179.455 u v^3 - 290.233 u^2 v^3 + 49.9563 u^3 v^3 == -381.29

59.281 - 107.678 u - 54.3923 u^2 + 53.6514 u^3 - 91.8892 v + 
  414.275 u v - 423.267 u^2 v + 103.006 u^3 v + 117.542 v^2 - 
  595.542 u v^2 + 704.098 u^2 v^2 - 235.713 u^3 v^2 - 28.0525 v^3 + 
  190.463 u v^3 - 318.228 u^2 v^3 + 174.94 u^3 v^3 == 29.0357
```

Sorry for such a "difficult" coefficients, these are from a real example. Wolfram Mathematica finds the roots perfectly using NSolve function, so the roots are:

```
{{u -> -0.948969 - 0.0248216 I, 
  v -> 1.18175 - 0.22013 I}, {u -> -0.948969 + 0.0248216 I, 
  v -> 1.18175 + 0.22013 I}, {u -> -0.634787, 
  v -> 0.144795}, {u -> -0.117873 - 0.421481 I, 
  v -> 0.161949 - 0.360139 I}, {u -> -0.117873 + 0.421481 I, 
  v -> 0.161949 + 0.360139 I}, {u -> 0.223577, 
  v -> 0.314141}, {u -> 0.247843 - 0.0362149 I, 
  v -> -0.994558 - 3.92549 I}, {u -> 0.247843 + 0.0362149 I, 
  v -> -0.994558 + 3.92549 I}, {u -> 0.470721 - 0.225239 I, 
  v -> 3.24012 - 1.37546 I}, {u -> 0.470721 + 0.225239 I, 
  v -> 3.24012 + 1.37546 I}, {u -> 0.667288 - 0.912625 I, 
  v -> 0.829839 + 0.545601 I}, {u -> 0.667288 + 0.912625 I, 
  v -> 0.829839 - 0.545601 I}, {u -> 0.75463 - 0.0960449 I, 
  v -> 0.390973 + 1.54337 I}, {u -> 0.75463 + 0.0960449 I, 
  v -> 0.390973 - 1.54337 I}, {u -> 1.81027 - 0.119485 I, 
  v -> -0.126177 - 0.281877 I}, {u -> 1.81027 + 0.119485 I, 
  v -> -0.126177 + 0.281877 I}, {u -> 1.91607, 
  v -> -0.465809}, {u -> 1.97797, v -> 0.629685}}
```

.

The problem is that the solving of such an equation system is just a step in a program written with C#, so I cannot use Wolfram Mathematica within it. If you know, can you please tell me, how to realize the numerical root finding algorithm? I do not ask you about writing me a code but just about an idea about a method using to achieve that like it is done with NSolve function of Wolfram Mathematica.

Thanks a lot! Waiting for your reply.

Comment: Bisection is a safe algorithm. But have a look at: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root-finding_algorithms

Comment: You think, this method can be applied to multivariate equation systems solving?

Comment: This is for 1D. For polynomials, see under 5)

Comment: No, I mean that bisection method can be applied to find all the roots of two-variate polynomial?

Comment: Read paragraph 5) at the indicated URL

Comment: You can eliminate a variable from two equations in the generic bicubic (that is, all coefficients are unique symbolic parameters) to get a degree 18 polynomial in the remaining variable. It has a leaf count of around 10^6. You could perhaps use it by instantiation (replacement of symbolic parameters with numeric values). To get this polynomial I did: `terms = Union[Flatten[Outer[Times, u^Range[0, 3], v^Range[0, 3]]]];
nterms = Length[terms];
acoeffs = Array[a, nterms];
bcoeffs = Array[b, nterms];
apoly = acoeffs.terms;
bpoly = bcoeffs.terms;
vres = Resultant[apoly, bpoly, u];`

Comment: Thank you! It’s already late here, and tomorrow I’ll try to perform this. But if it is not very difficult, couldn’t you please tell me what method uses the NSolve function itself? If it is possible, of course. So if you tell me the method the NSolve uses to solve the equation system I wrote, I could read about it and try to repeat it in my own code to achieve the result…

Comment: For multivariate systems `NSolve` uses primarily either of two methods, sparse homotopy continuation and an eigensystem decomposition based on first computing a numeric Groebner basis. Neither will be a straightforward translation to C#. You might find that library code already exists for the homotopy approach. Check [Jan Verschelde's web page(http://homepages.math.uic.edu/~jan/) for example. Also there is what's called the ["regeneration method"](https://www3.nd.edu/~sommese/preprints/RegenHSW.pdf) that might be feasible. I believe this will require a univariate root finder though.

Comment: Thank you for this link. And nonetheless, can you please tell, is there some way to use the NSolve function within some C# code, I mean using some dll or something? And is the answer is "no", if it isn't difficuilt, couldn't you show at least one of the formerly designated methods with Wolfram Mathematica code? Thanks!

Comment: I guess you could call the Wolfram engine from C#. As for implementation of these methods, that would take substantial work and is well outside of what could be done in this forum.